# Get every paragraph with specific id in body and make changes to another paragraph

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check every `p` with specific `id` in the `body` and when it's empty, it will print Open, to another paragraph `id`, otherwise if detects text will print Closed.

```js
$('#provlepsi').each(function(index) {
  if (jQuery('#provlepsi').is(':empty')) {
    // we're empty. do stuff.
    jQuery("#open-game").text("Open");
  } else {
    jQuery("#open-game").text("Closed");
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="game-wrapper">
  <?php while ( have_rows('live_game') ) : the_row();  ?>
    <div class="col-145">
      <p>
        <? the_sub_field('home_omada');  ?>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-145">
      <p>
        <? the_sub_field('opponent_team');  ?>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-145">
      <p>
        <? the_sub_field('lepto_protashs');  ?>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-145">
      <p>
        <? the_sub_field('score');  ?>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-145">
      <p id="provlepsi">
        <? the_sub_field('provlepsi_live_game');  ?>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-145">
      <p>
        <? the_sub_field('epityxia_agwna_live_game');  ?>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-145">
      <p id="open-game"></p>
    </div>
  <? endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: `$('#provlepsi').each` IDs must be unique - this, and your question text, implies you have multiple elements with the same ID.  `$('#provlepsi')` is essentially the same as `$('#provlepsi').first()` so will only ever be one element.  Recommend you use classes to identify rather than IDs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue here is that you're duplicating `id` attributes in the loop. They *have* to be unique within the DOM. To fix this use classes and traverse the DOM to relate elements to each other.

With that in mind you can select the `.open-game` elements directly and provide a function to `text()` which returns their content based on their related `.provlepsi`. Try this:

```js
$('.open-game').text(function() {
  var $wrapper = $(this).closest('.game-wrapper');
  return $wrapper.find('.provlepsi').is(':empty') ? 'Open' : 'Closed';
});
```

```css
.game-wrapper {
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="game-wrapper">
  <div class="col-145">
    <p class="provlepsi">provlepsi_live_game</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-145">
    <p>epityxia_agwna_live_game</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-145">
    <p class="open-game"></p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="game-wrapper">  
  <div class="col-145">
    <p class="provlepsi"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-145">
    <p>epityxia_agwna_live_game</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-145">
    <p class="open-game"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that the HTML has been amended slightly so that each `.game-wrapper` holds a single game only, not multiple.

Also be aware that you need to have no whitespace contained within an element when you intend to check it with `:empty`, so ensure you format the HTML/PHP output correctly, as shown above.

> In this code how can i also add a class properly if empty?

To add a class to the element at the same time you need to use a full `each()` loop along with `toggleClass`, like this:

```
$('.open-game').each(function() {
  var $game = $(this);
  var $wrapper = $game.closest('.game-wrapper');
  var isEmpty = $wrapper.find('.provlepsi').is(':empty');
  $game.text(isEmpty ? 'Open' : 'Closed').toggleClass('foo', isEmpty);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer. The game-wrapper also appears multiple times. It is not working properly do i need to change anything in the code? How can i ignore whitespace?

Comment: Without seeing what you have, I cannot really help. If the HTML is set as the answer shows it will work, as you can see in the example

Comment: In this code how can i also add a class properly if empty?